# Error when testing react components with jest and css-modules

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, css-modules

I'm trying to test my components with `jest`, `react`, `redux` but I keep getting the following error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run
        stream-react-redux/src/containers/App/App.css:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.app {

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I have followed the instructions on how to add the `identity-obj-proxy` and configuring my `.jestrc` file, but I keep getting the same error. The problem came when I started using *css-modules* and importing them in my components

Here is my `.jestrc`:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": [ "js", "jsx"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "^.+\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "verbose": true
}
```

I have also added the `["es2015", { "modules": false } ]` inside my `.babelrc` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after trying everything, I was  still getting the same error.

What I just noticed is that when I specify my config inside a `.jestrc` file my tests brake because of the `.css`, but when I do it from the `package.json` everything works.

**EDIT**

```
#package.json


  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.css$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }, 
    "transform": {
      "\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
```

Comment: Rename `.jestrc` to `jest.config.js` and restart jest)

Comment: Adding these jest settings to package.json worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the Jest docs and, just to be clear, did you install `identity-obj-proxy`?

`npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy`

Also, I see that the recommended file regex in the Jest docs is

`"\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"`

may try switching yours to match.

Finally, you could try a jest plugin like `jest-css-modules`

https://github.com/justinsisley/Jest-CSS-Modules

Comment: I have actually tried everything, but still getting the same error  What I just noticed is that when I specify my config inside a `.jestrc` file my tests brake because of the `.css` , but when I do it from the `package.json` everything works. I added an *edit* to my  question