# Setup Jest + React testing library using NextJS in TypeScript -- error setting upp jest.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I am trying to set up Jest with a NextJS application, currently in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.next/", "node_modules/"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/__tests__/setupTests.tsx"],
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  };
```

In my `setupTests.tsx` I have:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

However when I run `npm run test` I get the following error:

```
  Module identity-obj-proxy in the transform option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: ....
```

If I remove the line in `jest.config.js` I get:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

globals.css:2
    body {
         ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

    > 5 | import "../styles/globals.css";
```

What configuration should I use for the `css` and `scss` files?

** EDIT **

I made sure that `identity-obj-proxy` is in my devDependencies however, now I get an error:

```
Test suite failed to run

   Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

    > 5 | import "../styles/globals.css";
        | ^
      6 | import React from "react";
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Jest Could not locate module FileName.css (mapped as identity-obj-proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46287253/1870780)?

Comment: @juliomalves I made sure I have it in my devDependencies but I still get an error regarding the css

Comment: @ashes999 Did you find any solution for this error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install identity-obj-proxy. Run >>> yarn add -D identity-obj-proxy

Comment: this got me closer. now: error TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` or `processAsync` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a file `style-mock.js` with this content

```
module.exports = {};
```

2. Specify it inside the `moduleNameMapper` field of jest config

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^.+\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/jest-config/style-mock.js'
}
```

With this setup, it will mock all css import, hope it helps